# Find the multiplicity of root $x=a$ of polynomial $Q(x)= \frac{1}{2}$*$(x-a)(p'(x)+p'(a))-p(x)+p(a)$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

This is the problem I have: **We have polynomial $p(x)$, degree $n$, $n \in \Bbb N$. Find the multiplicity of root $x=a$ of polynomial $Q(x)= \frac{1}{2}$$(x-a)(p'(x)+p'(a))-p(x)+p(a)$.**

What have I considered:

1. I replaced $x=a$ where I do get $Q(a)=0$. That would mean root has, at least, multiplicity of one.
2. I thought about finding derivative of $Q(x)$ and thus concluding
   what multiplicity of root would be by replacing $x$ with $a$. So, if I get $Q^{(k)}=0$, then multiplicity is $k$. But, somehow, it does not seem to be the right way of looking at this problem as I progress using this idea.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's derive

$$Q^{'}(x)={1\over 2}\left(p^{'}(x)+p^{'}(a)\right)+{1\over 2}(x-a)p^{''}(x)-p^{'}(x)$$

Now substitute $a$

$$Q^{'}(a)={1\over 2}\left(p^{'}(a)+p^{'}(a)\right)+{1\over 2}(a-a)p^{''}(a)-p^{'}(a)=0$$

So multiplicity is at least $2$. Let's derive another time

$$\begin{align}Q^{''}(x)&={1\over 2}p^{''}(x)+{1\over 2}p^{''}(x)+{1\over 2}(x-a)p^{'''}(x)-p^{''}(x)\\&={1\over 2}(x-a)p^{'''}(x)\end{align}$$

and again substitute we get $Q^{''}(a)=0$ and multiplicity is at least $3$

The next derivative is not zero at $a$ as long as we do not make additional assumptions on the third derivative of $p$ at $a$.